# Bitcoin Core RPC cURL - importdescriptors failing on loaded wallet

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, json-rpc, output-script-descriptors, wallet-import

I am running the following request to load a wallet.

```
curl --location 'user:password@umbrel.local:8332/wallet/test_multisig"' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method":"loadwallet",
    "params": ["test_multisig"],
    "id": "test_multisig_wallet_load"
}'
```

It returns...

`{"result":null,"error":{"code":-35,"message":"Wallet \"test_multisig\" is already loaded."},"id":"test_multisig_wallet_load"}`

However I then run this exact request, and receive an error as if the wallet is not loaded.

```
curl --location 'user:password@umbrel.local:8332/wallet/test_multisig"' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data '{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method":"importdescriptors",
    "params":{
        "requests":[{
        "desc":"pkh(cSQPHDBwXGjVzWRqAHm6zfvQhaTuj1f2bFH58h55ghbjtFwvmeXR)",
        "active": false,
        "range": 20,
        "next_index": 0,
        "timestamp": "now", 
        "internal": false,
        "label": "test_multisig_wallet"
        }]
    }
}'
```

Error...
`{"result":null,"error":{"code":-18,"message":"Requested wallet does not exist or is not loaded"},"id":null}`

How can I import descriptors into a wallet so the wallet has a sequence of addresses?

Comment: What is the output of `listwallets`?

Comment: That wallet and a few others are listed. @PieterWuille

Comment: @PieterWuille The full result for `listwallets` is `{"result":["test_multisig","wallet2","wallet3"],"error":null,"id":"testWallet"}`. I receive the same error when running `importdescriptors` on all of these wallets.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain, I do think that these APIs need some more love at the level of usability. I am planning to spend some time on it because I had some problems too.

But before calling it a bug, we need to try to check if the workflow is the correct one.

Step 1: Create a wallet;
Step 1.1: Check if the wallet exists, if yes load it (in the URL you do not need to specify the `/wallet/<name_wallet>`)
Step 2: import your descriptors (you should work)

From the error that you gave, and from my experience I think
your wallet is not loaded, maybe because you are using the wrong URL (and here the question is why core is not failing?)

Keep us posted!